# Add a minimum of characters and delay google maps autocomplete API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to make the autocomplete function start only if there are at least 3 characters in my input and that it starts only after 3 seconds of delay from the last change of my input.

How can I do? Below I leave you the function that starts my inputs inside my form.

I followed the official google documentation to add the autocomplete to my form

This is my Javascript code

```
"use strict";

function initMap() {
  const componentForm = [
    'location',
    'locality',
  ];
  const autocompleteInput = document.getElementById('partenza');
  const autocompleteInputDestinazione = document.getElementById('destinazione');
  //Partenza
  const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(autocompleteInput, {
    componentRestrictions: { country: "it" },
    fields: ["address_components", "geometry", "name"],
  });
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function () {
    const place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
      // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and
      // pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
      window.alert('Nessun indirizzo trovato a: \'' + place.name + '\'');
      return;
    }
    renderAddress(place);
    fillInAddress(place);
  });
    

  //Destinazione
  const autocompleteDestinazione = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(autocompleteInputDestinazione, {
    componentRestrictions: { country: "it" },
    fields: ["address_components", "geometry", "name"],
  });
  autocompleteDestinazione.addListener('place_changed', function () {
    const place = autocompleteDestinazione.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
      // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and
      // pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
      window.alert('Nessun indirizzo trovato a: \'' + place.name + '\'');
      return;
    }
    renderAddress(place);
    fillInAddress(place);
  });

  function fillInAddress(place) {  // optional parameter
    const addressNameFormat = {
      'street_number': 'short_name',
      'route': 'long_name',
      'locality': 'long_name',
    };
    const getAddressComp = function (type) {
      for (const component of place.address_components) {
        if (component.types[0] === type) {
          return component[addressNameFormat[type]];
        }
      }
      return '';
    };
    document.getElementById('partenza').value = getAddressComp('street_number') + ' '
              + getAddressComp('route');
    document.getElementById('destinazione').value = getAddressComp('street_number') + ' '
              + getAddressComp('route');
    for (const component of componentForm) {
      // Location field is handled separately above as it has different logic.
      if (component !== 'location') {
        document.getElementById(component).value = getAddressComp(component);
      }
    }
  }

  function renderAddress(place) {
    map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
    marker.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't supported. If you insist on that logic, you will need to implement the component with [`google.maps.placesAutocompleteService`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-autocomplete-service#AutocompleteService). This will require you to manage the dropdown, input listeners, etc. See this [sample](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-queryprediction) for a start.

Note, there is no additional charge for the earlier requests as they are part of the same autocomplete session.